# Select second sheet not working. Gives error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, select

Simple question. Why does this code give an error?

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:I14").Copy Sheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Sheet2.Range("A1:X14").Select
```

Comment: Because you can't select cells on an inactive sheet, you need to activate sheet first. But read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: If You MUST use `.Select` first select `Sheet2`, then range on that second sheet

Comment: On which line do you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simple using of the next code. No selection necessary for such a task:

```
Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = sheet1.Range("A1:I14")
   Sheet3.Range("A1").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).value = rng.value
```